# JQuery when some go true then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm with a issue, the element `$("#el")` doesn't exist when I running my JS. The element has on different HTML but is on the same page.

I'm already try

```
$("#el").ready(addClickEv());

$(document).ready(addClickEv);

$.when($("#el").length > 0).then(addClickEv());

function addClickEv() {
    $("#el").on("click", function() {
        console.log("click");
    });
}
```

But any of this works. How can I do this?

Comment: when you say different HTML - is it inside of an iFrame?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is called 'event delegation' and it can be done very simply. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information